# client authentication using customtruststore on kestrel

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, client-certificates, kestrel

I'd like to authenticate a client certificate in a web project by using a custom trust store instead of a CA which's stored in the machine. The project is hosted in Linux environment and uses kestrel. I've tried using 'ClientCertificateValidation' callback configuring the Kestrel but that did not executed at all.

```
builder.WebHost.UseKestrel(options =>
    {
        options.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(opt =>
        {
            
            opt.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.AllowCertificate;
            opt.CheckCertificateRevocation = false;
            opt.ClientCertificateValidation = (certificate2, chain, arg3) =>
            {
                Log.Information(" CLIENT CERTIFICATION VALIDATION START ");
```

MS document says

> Certificate authentication happens at the TLS level, long before it
> ever gets to ASP.NET Core

So if I understand this correctly, there's no way of configuring this at code level. I wonder is there any approach to make this happen?

.

Comment: Yes, and Kestrel is handling that authentication at the TLS level.  That callback is designed for what you're trying to do if I understand correctly.  Are you sure you're sending the certificate?  I'd change it to `ClientCertificateMode.RequireCertificate` to ensure your request is correct.

Comment: Yes, you select the certificate from the browser's pop-up; tried with ```RequireCertificate``` nothing changed.

Comment: Will this be possible if you configure the TLS settings of host? This document indicates that [TLS settings can be configured with code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-6.0#kestrel-1).